# how do I make all the type of crime appear in the histogram?

Tags: r

I have a big dataset, and I have made a plot of a histogram, but the categorical variables "type of crime" on the x-axis is not visible. How do I make it visible in r?

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = TYPE.OF.CRIME))
g + geom_histogram(bins = 30, color = "gray", stat = "count")
```

Warning message:
Ignoring unknown parameters: binwidth, bins, pad

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know exactly what you're looking for. Perhaps a bar chart rather than a histogram?

```
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = TYPE.OF.CRIME, fill = TYPE.OF.CRIME)) 
g + geom_bar()
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(TYPE.OF.CRIME = sample(c("No reproducible data included",
                                  "Not stating problem clearly",
                                  "Not indicating packages used"), 30, replace = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`geom_histogram()` probably should not have categorical values without levels on its `x` axis as it works with intervals, you probably want `geom_bar()` rather than histogram?

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = TYPE.OF.CRIME))
g + geom_bar(color = "gray")
```

Comment: i actualy want a histogram, from the bar graph you plot, where there is "no reproducible data" , "not tating problem clearly",..., I want type of crime e.g "robery","assult" and ect.. all the type of crime should appear on the x-axis just like you have done in the bargraph above.

Comment: @augustinusntjamba That's actually not my plot, that's answer of @AllanCameron, my answer is only this short one! Just use Allan's code, only `df` states for your own data frame.

Comment: @augustinusntjamba It works, but it doesn't make sense as you have onordered categorical data like types of crime. The graphical output of geom_bar() is probably what you want - you get bars with counts of all the categories.

Comment: i have just post a question on the platform with a graph, perhaps if you can have a look at it , and see what my question is point at.